# Using iloc to normalize data by index instead of name in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a normalization function for a file. I have it working, but my auto-grader for this homework requires the column to be named by index instead of by name. I know I have to use iloc instead of loc, and this should be straight forward.

Here is my code currently:

```
def normalization (fname, attr, normType):
    '''
    Input Parameters:
        fname: Name of the csv file contiaining historical quotes
        attr: The attribute to be normalized 
        normType: The type of normalization 
    Output:
        a dictionary where each key is the original column value and each value is the normalised column value. 
    '''
    result = {
        
    }
    
    # your code here
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    # Extract the data of column specified (attr parameter)
    
    c = df.loc[:, attr]
    
    min_val = c.min()
    max_val = c.max()
    diff = max_val - min_val
    stdev = c.std()
    mean = c.mean()

    # If specified normalisation type is "min_max"
    if normType == "min_max":
        # Iterate through the data of extracted column
        for i in range(len(c)):
            # Normalise the data and store the normalised result
            # into result dictionary having key = original value,
            # value = normalised value)
            result[c[i]] = (c[i] - min_val) / diff
    else:
        if normType == "z_score":
        # Iterate through the data of extracted column
            for i in range(len(c)):
            # Normalise the data and store the normalised result
            # into result dictionary having key = original value,
            # value = normalised value)
                result[c[i]] = (c[i] - mean) / stdev

    # Result the final result
    return result
normalization("data/HistoricalQuotes.csv", "Open", "z_score")
```

currently this works if I call the attribute by name, but the autograder needs it to be called by index. Can anyone advise how to change this so that I could call :

```
normalization("data/HistoricalQuotes.csv", 0, "z_score")
```

?